# C++ define function via macro/template

Tags: c++

I am in a situation where I am required to define exact typedef compatible functions to ones that already exist. For example if I have:

```
class Foo {
public:
   void bar(int i);
   void __stdcall bar2(float b);
}

void bar_free(int i);
```

Then I need to define three functions:

```
void hkbar(Foo* _this, int i) {

}

void __stdcall hkbar2(Foo* _this, float b) {

}

void hkbar_free(int i);
```

I am able to get the typedef of the function I need to generate via c++ template tricks:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct GenFnType { using type = T; };

template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct GenFnType<Ret(__stdcall Class::*)(Args...), void>
{
    using type = Ret(__stdcall*)(Class*, Args...);
};

template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct GenFnType<Ret(__cdecl Class::*)(Args...), void>
{
    using type = Ret(__cdecl*)(Class*, Args...);
};

using T = typename GenFnType<decltype(&Foo::bar)>::type; // T is correct type
```

This however cannot be used to define a function. So here's my question, via C++ templates or Macros how can one essentially copy the type of one function to declare another one, such that it looks approximately like this:

```
DEFINE_CALLBACK(hkbar, &Foo::bar) {
   // arg names identical to foo::bar, or at least type identical and accessed like a1, a2, a3, etc.
   // potentially even args are grabbed via param pack or array/index. 
}
```

I've been just copying the function types, but I have to do this for *thousands* of functions and types. I cannot do this via pre-compile script because some of these functions come from very complicated headers like Windows where unknown macros and types are used that only the compiler can reliably know about at compile time.

Comment: No, you can't. C++ does not have [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). Use an external tool (`sed` `python` `perl` `awk`) to process the source file, extract the definitions and create output. `some of these functions come from very complicated headers` Proprocess input with a full-blown implementation of C preprocessor and use a C++-syntax aware tool to extract the definitions. There is no easy answer, I believe

Comment: Do you want to automatically define (i.e., implement) these functions as well? E.g., should `void hkbar(Foo* _this, int i)` actually just call `_this->bar(i);`? Or do you need to iterate through the parameters? Maybe give a full example what you want to do with a single function. Also why you need to do this, i.e. how do you intend to call `hkbar`, and why you can't directly call `Foo::bar`.

Comment: hkbar(Foo* _this, int i) will be injected with user logic. So it'd be like hkbar(Foo* _this, int i) { ...whatever... }. Usually this logic will end with _this->bar(i), though that's up to the user.

Comment: If that user logic is not the same every time, I don't really see what you actually want to save here by having a macro just for the function header.

Comment: I want type safety in the function declaration. The callback _must_ be the same type as the one i want to copy. It's quite alot of work, and error prone to copy hundreds of typedefs to generate these callbacks

Comment: You should pass `Foo` by reference or constant reference.  Consider pointers as evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work ok, credits to Can Bölük (@_can1357) who basically gave me the good parts of this. I can't get enable_if to handle the x64 case when all the calling conventions are the same so I disabled the other overloads via pre-processor.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct callback_type { using type = T; };

template<typename T>
using callback_type_t = typename callback_type<T>::type;

template<auto V>
using callback_type_v = typename callback_type<decltype(V)>::type;

#define MAKE_CALLBACK_IMPL(CCFROM, CCTO) template<typename F, typename Ret, typename... Args> \
auto make_callback(Ret(CCFROM*)(Args...), F&& f) \
{ \
    Ret(CCTO * fn)(Args...) = f; \
    return fn; \
} \
template<typename Ret, typename... Args> \
struct callback_type<Ret(CCFROM*)(Args...), void> \
{ \
    using type = Ret(CCTO*)(Args...); \
};

// switch to __VA_OPT__ when C++ 2a release. MSVC removes comma before empty __VA_ARGS__ as is.
// https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-preprocessor-progress-towards-conformance/
#define MAKE_CALLBACK_CLASS_IMPL(CCFROM, CCTO, ...) template<typename F, typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Args> \
auto make_callback(Ret(CCFROM Class::*)(Args...), F&& f) \
{ \
    Ret(CCTO * fn)(Class*, ## __VA_ARGS__, Args...) = f; \
    return fn; \
} \
template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Args> \
struct callback_type<Ret(CCFROM Class::*)(Args...), void> \
{ \
    using type = Ret(CCTO*)(Class*, ## __VA_ARGS__, Args...); \
};

#ifndef _WIN64 
MAKE_CALLBACK_IMPL(__stdcall, __stdcall)
MAKE_CALLBACK_CLASS_IMPL(__stdcall, __stdcall)

MAKE_CALLBACK_IMPL(__cdecl, __cdecl)
MAKE_CALLBACK_CLASS_IMPL(__cdecl, __cdecl)

MAKE_CALLBACK_IMPL(__thiscall, __thiscall)
MAKE_CALLBACK_CLASS_IMPL(__thiscall, __fastcall, char*)
#endif

MAKE_CALLBACK_IMPL(__fastcall, __fastcall)
MAKE_CALLBACK_CLASS_IMPL(_fastcall, __fastcall)

#define HOOK_CALLBACK(pType, name, body) typedef callback_type_v<pType> ##name##_t; \
callback_type_v<pType> name = make_callback(pType, [](auto... _args) body )

template <int I, class... Ts>
decltype(auto) get_pack_idx(Ts&&... ts) {
    return std::get<I>(std::forward_as_tuple(ts...));
}

// for member functions this is essentially 1's indexed because first param is this*
#define GET_ARG(idx) get_pack_idx<idx>(_args...);
```

```
Usage:
HOOK_CALLBACK(&IWbemServices::ExecQuery, hkExecQuery, {
    auto orig = (hkExecQuery_t)pOrigExecQuery;

    BSTR strQuery = GET_ARG(2);
    Log(L"ComIWbemService!ExecQuery {:#x} {}\n", RetAddr, PU_BS(strQuery));
    return orig(_args...);
});
```